# PHP Creating a function for Shortening Large Numbers to English Equivalent Name Based Decimals

Tags: php, function, numbers

In my database I have a store of property values in Int form. They range from $1000 to $100,000,000. How would I create a function that could break this information down to symbolized text/decimal form.

For example

1,300,000 would become 1.3 Million

250,000 would become 250 Thousand

10,300,000 would become 10.3 Million

What I'm trying to get is the English equivalent of the long number

Any Idea on where to start?

Comment: This question is a bit ambiguous since "1.3 million" could also be "one point three million" or "one million three hundred thousand". Apparently you want to convert to English but just up to a certain point; you should specify that point. Specially problematic are small numbers, since 1000 can be translated to "one thousand" but 2000 cannot be "2 thousand", makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used something similar to this once:

```
function abbNumber($var)
{
    if(($var/1000000000)>1)
    {
        $retVal=round($var/1000000000,1).' hundred million';
    }
    else if(($var/1000000)>1)
    {
        $retVal=round($var/1000000,1).' million';
    }
    else if(($var/1000)>1)
    {
        $retVal=round($var/1000,1).' thousand';
    }
    else
    {
        $retVal=$var;
    }
    return $retVal;
}

echo abbNumber(5234000);

?>
// 5.2 million

echo abbNumber(5234000000);
5.2 hundred million
echo abbNumber(523400000);
523.4 million
echo abbNumber(523400);
523.4 thousand
echo abbNumber(5.234);
5.234
```

Answer (score 1):

Start here:

```
$x = 1300000;
$text = ($x / 1000000) . ' Million';
```

Then, detect the number of digits in your source number to check whether it makes more sense to divide by thousand or a million.

Then, apart from dividing, also round the number, so 1,387,238 is translated to 1.4 Million instead of 1.387238 Million.